# npm install stops working

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm

I have checked many stackoverflow answers but havent found any that can fix my current problem, after running npm install the installation just stops after a while, this is result from the command: npm install -verbose
I am running on Windows 10, Powershell adminmode.

```
   ^CPS C:\Users\hjort\Documents\git\nuhet> npm install -verbose
   npm info it worked if it ends with ok
   npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
   npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-   cli.js',
   npm verb cli   'install',
   npm verb cli   '-verbose' ]
   npm info using npm@2.14.4
   npm info using node@v4.1.2
   npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\hjort\Documents\git\nuhet\package.json
   npm verb install where, deps [ 'C:\\Users\\hjort\\Documents\\git\\nuhet',
   npm verb install   [ 'laravel-elixir',
   npm verb install     'bootstrap-sass',
   npm verb install     'gulp',
   npm verb install     'laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster' ] ]
   npm verb install where, peers [ 'C:\\Users\\hjort\\Documents\\git\\nuhet', [] ]
   npm verb installManyTop reading for lifecycle C:\Users\hjort\Documents\git\nuhet\package.json
   npm info preinstall @
   npm verb readDependencies loading dependencies from C:\Users\hjort\Documents\git\nuhet\package.json
   npm verb cache add spec gulp@^3.8.8
   npm verb addNamed ">=3.8.8 <4.0.0" is a valid semver range for gulp
   npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp not in flight; fetching
   npm verb cache add spec laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster@^3.0.0
   npm verb addNamed ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0" is a valid semver range for laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster
   npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster not in flight; fetching
   npm verb cache add spec laravel-elixir@^3.0.0
   npm verb addNamed ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0" is a valid semver range for laravel-elixir
   npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir not in flight; fetching
   npm verb cache add spec bootstrap-sass@^3.0.0
   npm verb addNamed ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0" is a valid semver range for bootstrap-sass
   npm verb addNameRange registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-sass not in flight; fetching
   npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster
   npm verb request no auth needed
   npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 13:34:57
   npm verb request id 02f42720181b5dc2
   npm verb etag "YKMBAE0ADCRKINBWWZE2VLG"
   npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster
   npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
   npm verb request no auth needed
   npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 13:34:57
   npm verb etag "9LDNWINP8N9T19SMZNI424E8Q"
   npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
   npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-sass
   npm verb request no auth needed
   npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 13:34:57
   npm verb etag "222LDEHR46XIS27VQ27I94MMD"
   npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-sass
   npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir
   npm verb request no auth needed
   npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 13:34:57
   npm verb etag "CLCFW1HL59PBEG7YUCVBFSBCP"
   npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir
   npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp
   npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp from cache
   npm verb get saving gulp to C:\Users\hjort\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\gulp\.cache.json
   npm verb addNamed "3.9.0" is a plain semver version for gulp
   npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir
   npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir from cache
   npm verb get saving laravel-elixir to C:\Users\hjort\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\laravel-elixir\.cache.json
   npm verb addRemoteTarball https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp/-/gulp-3.9.0.tgz not in flight; adding
   npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp/-/gulp-3.9.0.tgz',
   npm verb addRemoteTarball   'cf1fba4cb558bb8c6ae6c9613f583ae2620d214a' ]
   npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-sass
   npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-sass from cache
   npm verb get saving bootstrap-sass to C:\Users\hjort\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\bootstrap-sass\.cache.json
   npm verb addNamed "3.3.2" is a plain semver version for laravel-elixir
   npm verb addNamed "3.3.5" is a plain semver version for bootstrap-sass
   npm verb addRemoteTarball https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir/-/laravel-elixir-3.3.2.tgz not in flight; adding
   npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir/-/laravel-elixir-3.3.2.tgz',
   npm verb addRemoteTarball   'bc72a362ed0233a2d14985327e4a7d8a42781e6c' ]
   npm verb addRemoteTarball https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-sass/-/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.tgz not in flight; adding
   npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-sass/-/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5.tgz',
   npm verb addRemoteTarball   '89f213751ee01cde0dc1f63a51e9b3521dd20ebc' ]
   npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster
   npm verb etag https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster from cache
   npm verb get saving laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster to C:\Users\hjort\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster\.cache.json
   npm verb addNamed "3.0.0" is a plain semver version for laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster
   npm verb addRemoteTarball https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster/-/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster-3.0.0.tgz not in flight; adding
   npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster/-/laravel-elixir-css-url-adjuster-3.0.0.tgz',
   npm verb addRemoteTarball   'f92d5c673cde60c48a3048d2bd91eeb2ce02d50a' ]
```

Comment: "hangs itself" like with a rope? :D

Comment: changed title so it don't sound like my npm is trying it kill itself

Comment: what is the version of your `npm`? Try `npm -v`. You are trying to install `laravel elixir`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be problem with your npm version or temp directories - there is a similar issue resloved on npm GitHub - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7590

Check if you have two temp directories set in your .npmrc:

```
npm config ls -l
```

Look for lines defining the tmp config variable. If you find more than one, remove all but one of them.

Also try updating your npm version to newest.

Comment: Thank you, I had a second path in my tmp. it is not fixed

Comment: I guess it is "now" fixed :)